# Remote launch and shutdown of Azure server within .Net/C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have a VM on Azure that is used to run some computationally intensive work. Before I let users loose on it, I would like to build a small desktop app in C# that allows users to remotely start the Azure VM, launch an RDP connection to it and shut down the VM.

I have updated my Visual Studio to include the Azure libraries, but having spent some time with Google, I can't find any good code samples to help with this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: You should use powershell

Comment: @Liam - the users are very non-technical and don't want to have to run scripts. The brief is clear - a simple app with a few buttons to push.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Azure Management Libraries for .Net, https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/simpler-azure-management-libraries-for-net/

It allows you to manage your VM's. See this code repo for an example project for managing VM's including starting and stopping: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-dotnet-manage-vm

You can easily create a desktop app that calls these libraries.

An alternative, as Liam commented, would be to use powershell and start the powershell scripts using a desktop app. The desktop app could provide the necessary parameters. The advantage of that approach is that you can always automate tasks with the same powershell scripts.

Comment: Execution of powershell scripts is banned (corporate policy) so I'll take a look at the github code samples.

Comment: I have tried using the code samples in your links but I can't install most of the libraries required. I have upgraded my VS2012 with update 5, upgraded .Net to 4.6.2, cleared out all installed libraries and re-installed but NuGet tells me that it can't find most of the libraries. I even got another machine running VS2015 and Win10 and had the same problems. Did you try any of the code samples? Were you able to download the libraries?

Comment: The code sample is the .net core application. Have you installed the .net core SDK? If no, please have  a try download the [.netCore](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015) SDK. And try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Preparation to run the [demo code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-dotnet-manage-vm):

1.[net core tool](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015)  [Required visual studio2015 update 3]

2.Registry an app in the Azure AD and create service principal for accessing the resource. More detail please refer to the [document](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2016/10/21/using-the-azure-arm-rest-apin-get-access-token/).

3.Prepare the  authentication file with the content as following format. The values can be got from the step 2.

```
subscription=########-####-####-####-############
client=########-####-####-####-############
key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
tenant=########-####-####-####-############
managementURI=https\://management.core.windows.net/
baseURL=https\://management.azure.com/
authURL=https\://login.windows.net/
graphURL=https\://graph.windows.net/
```

4. Change the azure authentication  file path

```
AzureCredentials credentials = AzureCredentials.FromFile("Full path of your AzureAuthFile");
```

I create a demo use the common console application (Preparation 2,3 also needed). I also have tested it. The following is the detail steps:

1. Install the [Microsoft Azure Management Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/)

[image]
2. Add the demo code as following

```
AzureCredentials credentials = AzureCredentials.FromFile(@"full file path");
            var azure = Azure
                .Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.BASIC)
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithDefaultSubscription();
            foreach (var virtualMachine in azure.VirtualMachines.ListByGroup("resource Group name").Where(virtualMachine => virtualMachine.ComputerName.Equals("vm name")))
            {
               //virtualMachine.Start();
               virtualMachine.PowerOff();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

3. Debug the demo project

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom - many thanks for taking the time to try your solution to this issue. With the help of some people at Microsoft, I found the problem, which I have posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725122/nuget-for-microsoft-azure-packages In short, the problem arose from starting the project with VS2012, migrating through various updates to arrive at VS2015 with updates. This created a string of dependencies that caused it to fall over.