# NuGet for Microsoft.Azure packages

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am trying to write an application that uses Microsoft Azure. I am using VS2012 and have installed update 5. I also updated NuGet to the latest version.

In my code, I am using the following:

```
    using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resource.Fluent.Authentication;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resource.Fluent.Core;
```

When I go to package manager, 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute' installs successfully, but the Fluent and Resource packages won't - it says that it's unable to find the packages.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Comment: I have now tried this on another machine that has Visual Studio 2016 and .Net 4.6.2 and have the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

You need to install the **Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent** package as well. In Package Manager Console, target your project and run:

**Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent -Pre**

This is a **pre-release package** so it will not show up unless you include the -Pre option or select the Include prerelease option within the NuGet window (if you are adding packages this way).

Carl

Comment: that only partly worked as there were problems with other dependencies in packages. I also got a reply with some suggestions from Microsoft last night so will try to implement that this morning and will report back.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's taken me a little while to get to the bottom of this, but here is what went wrong. The project started life on VS2012 with .Net 4.5. I then went through various upgrades to VS2012 update 5, latest version of NuGet, .Net 4.6.2. When that didn't work, I spun up a development machine on Azure with VS2015 (update 3 and .Net 4.6.2) and moved the project over but that still didn't work.

The problem was that there were too many dependencies that tagged along from the original project. The answer was to start a fresh project on the Azure machine, copy my code over and then install the various Azure packages - it worked first time.